# simple python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling to find out a simple python regex, which would mean :

several white spaces (/n /t /r ) followed by at least one character other than whitespace (a-zA-Z0-9, every operator, etc) and again several white spaces. Also there don't have to be any whitespace. So e.g. "c" , "\nc" , "c\t" is correct, but \n is not.
So far i have stg like:

```
  re.compile('\s*\S+\s*')
```

but I'm not sure if it is entirely correct..is it?

Thank you for your answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct:

```
>>> re.search('\s*\S+\s*', '   foo   ').group(0)
'   foo   '
>>> re.search('\s*\S+\s*', 'foo   ').group(0)
'foo   '
>>> re.search('\s*\S+\s*', 'foo').group(0)
'foo'
```

Remember that Python has an interpreter. It's pretty awesome, so use it!